# How do I call a trait method on a reference and not the referenced value?

Tags: reference, rust, traits

I have a reference (`foo`) that implements the trait `IntoIterator<Item = &T>`. I want to call the trait method `into_iter` directly on `foo` (i.e. the reference itself) and not `*foo` (the referenced value), as seems to be happening, since the type of `*foo` also implements `IntoIterator` (albeit with `Item = T`). I've tried UFCS, but even that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Here's my actual code:

```
fn csl_join<'a, V, T>(value: &V) -> String 
    where V: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>, 
          T: 'a + ToString 
{
    itertools::join(value.into_iter().map(|v: &T| v.to_string()), ",")
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what you want to achieve. `&V` does not have a method `into_iter`, because it doesn't implement `IntoIterator`. `V` has said method because it implements said trait. Also: there is an important difference between `&IntoIterator<...>` and `&V where V: IntoIterator<...>`. So for the case that I'm not the only confused reader: could you clarify the question a bit? :)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: My bad. I was being stupid with the trait bounds! I will delete the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Or put another way: what difference in behavior do you expect when calling on `value` instead of `*value`?

Comment: Ok sure, glad I could help (although you could keep the question to share the knowledge?)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Sure, the solution was changing the bound to `&V: IntoIterator...`, which was kind of obvious I guess. ;) Except it's late, and I wasn't thinking. Then I just needed to add some explicit type parameters. But if you still think it's helpful to post the code, I can do it.

Comment: If you have the time, why not edit the question and self answer? ;-) The [rust] tag is still small-ish; any knowledge would help. At least I don't think this question was asked before...

Comment: Okay, that's done!

Answer (score 5):

I ended up solving this issue just after posting it, thanks to @LukasKalbertodt's helpful comments. It turns out I simply wanted the type bound to be `&V: IntoIterator<Item = &T>`, to match the intended usage in the function body (duh!).

So the code becomes:

```
fn csl_join<'a, 'b, V, T>(value: &'a V) -> String
    where V: 'a,
          &'a V: IntoIterator<Item = &'b T>,
          T: ToString + 'b
{
    itertools::join(value.into_iter().map(|v: &T| v.to_string()), ",")
}
```

I'll leave this here in case it assists someone else, by chance.